# OS X 10.10.3 launchctl Permission denied

Tags: python, macos, shell, launchctl

I execute `launchctl start com.xxx.xxx.plist`

I can find `AutoMakeLog.err` and the content :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/xxxx/Downloads/Kevin/auto.py", line 67, in <module>
output = open(file_name, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '2015-04-22-09:15:40.log'
```

plist content :

```
<array>
  <string>/Users/xxxx/Downloads/Kevin/auto.sh</string>
</array>
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
<dict>
    <key>Minute</key>
    <integer>30</integer>
    <key>Hour</key>
    <integer>08</integer>
</dict>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/Users/xxxx/Downloads/Kevin/AutoMakeLog.log</string>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/Users/xxx/Downloads/Kevin/AutoMakeLog.err</string>
```

auto.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/python /Users/xxxx/Downloads/Kevin/auto.py
```

auto.py

```
file_name = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))
file_name += '.log'
output = open(file_name, 'w')
output.writelines(response.text)
output.close()
```

auto.sh and auto.py have chomd 777

PS: I direct execution auto.sh there is nothing error.

Comment: Looks like you have to run with `sudo` because it doesn't have permissions to that file or directory

Comment: how can launchctl execut python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even ***user-specific* `launchd` jobs** on OSX are **executed with `/`as the current directory.**

**Since `auto.py` is creating a file with a *mere filename, without path*, it effectively tries to create a file in `/` and fails due to insufficient privileges.**

Thus, either change to a directory the current user can create files in, or specify an explicit path; e.g. (assuming `import os`):

```
file_name = os.getenv('HOME') + '/' + time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S', time.localtime(time.time()))
```

---

As for **how you can run your `python` scripts *directly***, without the need for an intermediate shell script:

In your plist file, specify the command to execute as follows:

```xml
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>python</string>
    <string>/Users/xxxx/Downloads/Kevin/auto.py</string>
  </array>
```

Note that you needn't specify a path for `python`, because it is in the `$PATH` when `launchd` runs your job.

However, note that the `$PATH` contains *fewer* entries than what you see in `Terminal`, and a notable *absence* is `/user/local/bin`; the value is (as of OSX 10.10.3):

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding this answer for visibility, although was not causing the original issue in this question.

Due to changes in **macOS 10.14 Mojave** `launchd` commands have more security restrictions now. If you see `Permission denied` errors for files and directories owned by your user, then see [Q: How Do I Grant Root Access To User Files in Mojave](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339020/how-do-i-grant-root-access-to-user-files-in-mojave) for a possible fix.